# How to add multiple controllers to one view in Angular JS route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, in this official tutorial, only ONE controller PhoneListCtrl is assigned to the view /phones. What if I have multiple controllers for this view?

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not assign the controllers directly to the view?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to attack this concern.

- You can use the `ng-controller` directive within a view:

  ```
  <div ng-controller="someOtherController">
      <input ng-model="propertyOfSomeOtherControllersScope" />
  </div>
  ```

  - You can use the angular-ui team's [ui-router module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). In short, this allows you to have multiple named views within a single "state", which are idiomatically like their "routes". Way too much going on with it to describe it in full here, but it's a great module for almost any project.
  - This is kind of the same as the first solution, but you could use `ng-include` to include another partial which explicitly declares its controller. Basically, in your main file: `<div ng-include="'file2.html'"></div>` and in file2.html: `<div ng-controller="someOtherController"></div>`.

These three things just jump right to mind, there are certainly other ways to go about this. And in some cases, you might want a directive instead of just another controller within a single view. Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.